# Border-Radius Crazy CSS disappeareance in Webkit with Facebook Page Plugin

Tags: html, css, iframe, webkit

I found a *very weird* bug today while developing a new site, I really don't know why in the hell it's happening, but I think someone might know.

I made a navigation menu fixed to the top-right part of the page, within it, a big div made round from a lot of border-radius.

It was working very fine and normal untill I added to the right bar a facebook page plugin.
When the bottom of that div goes over the title of the page in the plugin, the border-radius disappears. It stays a square div while it's there, goes back to round if I scroll the page and stays round until it's "touching" that very specific part of that page plugin.

I really don't have a clue about why, here's some code for better understanding:

```
.nav {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
    z-index:9999;
}
.face {
    position:absolute;
    width: 20%; 
    background:#F93;
    top:5px;
    right:10px;
    border-radius:9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.face:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 95%;

}
.face a img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%
}
.menu{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:1em;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    margin-top:3%;

}

.menu a {
    padding:0 0.5em;
    border-radius:4em;
}
```

And also:

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="menu">
<a href="#">menu</a><a href="#">menu</a><a href="#">menu</a><a href="#">menu</a>
</div><br/>
<div class="name">
<h2>name</h2>
</div>
<div class="face">
<a href="#"><img src="i/image.png"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

By the way, it seems to happen only on webkit browsers, on firefox it looks very normal, didn't even test in internet explorer.

EDIT: Just tested on Internet Explorer and SURPRISINGLY it did work very well, this is now very very weird

EDIT2: Some Screenshots for even more clarification:

Before touching the title:

[image: Just before touching that title]

After it gets on that very specific spot:

[image: That very specific spot]

Further down:

[image: Further Down]

Anytime it's over the title it's not round, elsewhere it's fine.

EDIT3: I found out that there was another place the bug was happening; I have a jquery slider on the page; I had an Opacity effect on hover on some controls, when these opacity was being animated, it reproduced the disappearing border-radius problem, and then went back to normal by itself; Removing opacity CSS rule from the neutral state made the bug stop happening while hovering the slider, but it keeps hapenning while that div is over the facebook plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a fix for the problem, that I can only think I didn't thought before because I was too tired. ^^'

First of all, I found out that this bug was even weirder than I thought, thinking back how the opacity on another element seemed to affect it, I tried changing the image opacity, then, I found out that the div that contained it was in fact, still round.

Even though the image was being cut by the `overflow:hidden;` it wasn't being cut by the border-radius of the parent div.

I fixed it by putting border-radius on the image too, so now it is round even when over that plugin, the problem is gone now.

I hope someday this gets found by some webkit developers and the identify and fix that bug, it was really weird.

Thanks Henry for the help too!

TL;DR

Fixed by using `border-radius` on both parent div and image.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more going on here because of the Facebook plugin, but it sounds like this is a problem of not taking into account Webkit CSS rules. If that's the problem, I'm surprised that Firefox isn't giving you trouble. The standard way to style rounded corners with cross-browser support is to give `border-radius`, then `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`:

```
.menu {
    ...
    border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
    ...
}
.menu a {
    ...
    border-radius: 4em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4em;
}
```

Comment: The menu div actually isn't having any kind of problems, the face div is x. x
Even so, I'll try using the vendor prefixes and see if it fixes o7

Comment: Ok, just tried, the problem continues, even with the vendor prefixes;
I tried changing the #face div border-radius to 10em instead of 9999px too, seeing if it would change anything and nope, didnt do anything. (By the way, thanks for the shorthand border-radius properties)

Comment: So even with vendor prefixes everywhere, the area inside the red line isn't rounded? https://jsfiddle.net/enry/4hafL21n/

Comment: It is perfectly round, in the site it's also round, it's just stops being round while it's over the facebook page plugin page title, and then goes back to normal when it's not over it. I'll make some screenshots for clarification

Comment: Right, understood. I was just trying to be sure which part you were talking about. So it must be something to do with the facebook plugin right? You haven't provided any info on that

Comment: Yeah, it could have something to do with the plugin itself, or maybe because the plugin renders the page inside an IFrame, but probably because of the plugin itself.

Comment: Bummer, sounds like fixing it won't be convenient. But maybe you'll figure out the bug and can tell facebook about it!

Comment: Probably it's more of a Webkit bug, as I found out another part of the page causing the same bug, at least I fixed the other place it was happening, one step closer, I suppose! ^^'